# What is physical significance of Bit Error Rate (BER) and Outage Probability?

Tags: digital-communications, signal-power, fading-channel, communication-standard

I am trying to understand the physical significance of Bit Error Rate (BER) and Outage Probability especially in low power wireless communication such as internet of things (IoT).

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: exactly what the name say: the amount of bits that are wrong, and the probability that you have a communication outage, respectively. What that means for your application: we can't know. IoT doesn't mean anything other than that there's connected devices. You will need to do your modeling of what it means for *your* system to have {BER} bits wrong, or a probability of {Outage Probability} to not be able to communicate yourself.

Comment: Ok sir... Thanks for your reply.